# How do you say “Who are you forbidding from entering the club?”

Tags: grammaire

Person 1: Who are you forbidding from entering the club?

Bouncer: Just that boy.

---

I’m trying to figure out how to say “Who are you forbidding from entering the club?”

Collins dictionary says “to forbid sb to do sth” equals [« défendre à qn de faire qch »](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/forbid) and also equals [« interdire à qn de faire qch »](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/interdire).

So I’m proposing

« À qui défendez-vous d’entrer dans le club ? » or « À qui interdisez-vous d’entrer dans le club ?

Is this grammatically correct? I’m asking this question because some people have told me no. They’ve said that the answer is « À qui interdisez-vous l'entrée du club ? » et « À qui défendez-vous l'entrée du club ? » with which I don’t disagree. But I don’t see why mine aren’t grammatically correct. So I would just like to know if it is the case that mine are grammatically correct but it’s just that they aren’t used in daily french.

Comment: What language registry is expected? All of the suggested sentences are not very likely to be heard in a dialog with a bouncer...

Comment: I don't know why, and not even if my understanding is grammatically correct, but my first read was "Who are you, forbidding from entering the club?", which I'd translate "Qui êtes-vous pour interdire l'entrée au club ?"

Answer (score 2):

Both

> *À qui défendez-vous d’entrer dans le club ?* (→ *J'ai défendu à ce garçon d'entrer dans le club.*)

and

> *À qui interdisez-vous d’entrer dans le club ?* (→ *J'ai interdit à ce garçon d'entrer dans le club.*)

sound slightly weird to me although their affirmative counterpart are fine.

The suggested alternatives:

> ***À qui interdisez-vous l'entrée du club ?*** (→ *J'ai interdit l'entrée du club à ce garçon.*)

and

> *À qui défendez-vous l'entrée du club ?* (→ *J'ai défendu l'entrée du club à ce garçon.*)

are more idiomatic, especially the first one, but will hardly appear in a real dialog with a bouncer.

Here are what I believe is more likely to be heard in that context:

> *Vous interdisez l'entrée à qui ?*

> *C'est à qui que vous interdisez l'entrée ?*

> *C'est qui que vous empêchez d'entrer ?*

> *C'est qui que vous refusez/refoulez à l'entrée ?*

> *C'est à qui que vous refusez l'accès ?*

Comment: Autre suggestion pour ce contexte: *refouler*.

Answer (score -1):

Both of your constructions are correct and have the same meaning. Moreover, they are formulations that you can use in daily French.